# Why does my server run great when packaged in a command-line tool, but bog down when run inside an NSApplication?

Tags: objective-c, performance, sockets, server, grand-central-dispatch

Environment: macOS Mojave, 6-core I7 Mac mini.

I have written a ModBus server using LibModbus to provide the Modbus-logic, and a GCD file-descriptor dispatch-source to implement the server logic.

When run inside a simple command-line target, using `dispatch_main()` in main.c as recommended, the server runs great -- easily handling an unrelenting *thousands* of ModBus requests per second. The internal use of non-blocking sockets and SO_REUSEADDR keeps the server happily recycling the same socket indefinitely. It uses almost no CPU and negligible RAM.

If I take *exactly* the same source code and invoke it inside an `NSApplication` app wrapper, it becomes a worthless *pig*, incapable of reliably handling mere dozens of requests per second without choking after 256 requests (interesting number, but what does it *mean*?). The app wrapper has nothing else going on -- its only job is to host the server.

I have tried instrumenting the app version with Instruments, but none of the Instruments provided any information that was useful to me, other than that it seemed like the app version was spawning a lot of threads.

To emphasize the rudimentary nature of the app version, here is the entire contents of the AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(applicationDidBeginRunLoop:)
                           withObject: nil
                        waitUntilDone: NO
     ];
}

- (void) applicationDidBeginRunLoop: (id) ignored
{
    self.server = [GCDModbusSlave modbusSlave];
    [self.server run];
}
```

-- and here is the main() from the tool version:

```
int main(void)
{
    modbusSlave = [GCDModbusSlave modbusSlave];
    [modbusSlave run];
    dispatch_main();
}
```

I am hoping that I have just forgotten something stupid, and I am looking for good questions.

Comment: Without knowing how the server is actually launched and how it manages queues/threads, there isn't enough information here.   dispatch_main() is basically "run without main thread" whereas your app delegate code is "run in main thread".   What does `-run` do?!

Answer (score 0):

I determined that the core issue was that the code was just too slow and was piling up un-handled blocks in the various queues. The clue was that I was seeing "overcommit" queues when I paused the code when it was bogging down.

I went back and rewrote the server loop omitting the ModBus calls and substituting a rudimentary socket protocol to simplify the structure. I fairly soon had a server that would run stably at 5K accesses/second, and keep up with the demand stream. At 10K it can't keep up, but still runs without issues. It uses barely any memory and CPU when running at 5K.

Next I will subclass the server to do ModBus instead of the rudimentary protocol. Since the ModBus library code is just vanilla C, with no threads or GCD calls, I hope that this part will be uneventful.